# selected item change ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Is there any way to prevent changing the selected item in a ComboBox only if for certain conditions?  I want to allow update the selected item's displayValue in the ComboBox. But I don't want user to change the selected item when it's being updated. This is a windows application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your class:

```
private int _selectedIndex = 0;
```

Inside your form load method:

```
comboBox1.Enter += new EventHandler(comboBox1_Enter);
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Then the rest of the code:

```
protected void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (true) { // Add your validation or certain condition here.
        (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
    }
}

protected void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _selectedIndex = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would like to prevent opening the list of items. This solution makes little confusing for the users.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting set the Enabled property to false.  (Or some third-party toolkits like Telerik have a ComboBox with a ReadOnly property.)

Comment: @David: I want all to user to edit the Text of the selected item but changing the selected item.

Comment: You can type and edit the selected item's displayValue. I want to provide that functionality while preventing the disable to selected item.

Comment: The ComboBox is designed to let the user (1) select an item from a pre-defined list and optionally (2) type in a custom value that isn't already in the list.  If I understand correctly, the functionality you're describing would require a custom control.

Comment: No you haven't got it propery. I just want to update the selected item. But I don't want user to change the selected item when it's being updated.

Comment: I don't know that the ComboBox is designed to allow this ...  I can't say that I've ever come across any code that does anything like this.  That's why I recommended a custom control.
Please note that this is well beyond the scope of your original question.